# Enable user to select location from drop down or map?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, core-location

I have an app that automatically gets the user's location via GPS if enabled, but I'd like to provide an option to allow the user to manually input the location. I'm not sure how this can work form a UX or technical perspective. Below is my screenshot from my table.

[image]

If the user disables `Automatic`, I'm not sure what the best way for the table to react or what controls to use. Should I open a modal view and display drop downs for the user to select their: country > Province > City? Or maybe to allow them to place a pin on a map? Could it be very simple to implement a text box that allows the user to enter an address then I can geocode it instead? I eventually want to end up with coordinates in my app code.

What kind of data or services do I need to accomplish this? It's a small feature, but I'm finding it to have many factors involved. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest implementing a UIMapView with 1. a UISearchBar above it 2. a UIButton that pings the user to their current location, to the right of the searchBar and above the mapView 3. an 'Add Location' button at the bottom left of the mapView and 4. a 'Cancel' button at the bottom right of the mapView. The 'Add Location' button would use the center coordinate of the map.

When a user switches from 'Automatic' to 'Manual' put a button to the right of the label that says 'Add Location' or 'Update Location'. Pressing this button would animate the previously discussed view to sweep in, or however you want to animate it.

Good luck with your design!

[image]

Comment: Wow nice!! Full featured but not cluttered.